# How to cpulimit the `npm install` process?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Whenever I run the npm install command to install dependencies, CPU usage is getting too high, so I get a CPU alarm from my companies' infra.
I want to reduce CPU usage even if I compromise on memory or speed.
Is there any way to reduce CPU usage of `npm install` process?

I tried to use `cpulimit`, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried `cpulimit -l 50 -- 'yarn --production'`, but CPU usage is still high when I see it in `htop` or `top`.

ps. I'm using AWS ElasticBeanstalk AMI 2 (5.5.1) with Node.js 16.14.0, npm 8.3.1

Comment: Which is your host OS ?

Comment: @Shankar I'm using AWS ElasticBeanstalk AMI 2 (5.5.1) with Node.js 16.14.0, npm 8.3.1